# Gensim Library not recognized in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, gensim

I have a bIg data platform. On that I install Anaconda. When I ssh to my account on the platform and open up a Python interpreter in terminal it works fine when I import the gensim library. I had earlier installed this library using

```
Conda install gensim

$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import gensim
/home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py:1015: UserWarning: Pattern library is not installed, lemmatization won't be available.
  warnings.warn("Pattern library is not installed, lemmatization won't be available.")
```

If you see it does import the library (just gives some warning for Pattern library). However when I open up Jupyter notebook and try to import the same library there it gives the following:

```
In [11]:

import gensim 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-0539d76422c6> in <module>()
----> 1 import gensim

ImportError: No module named gensim
```

Am not sure why the same library which is installed is not working in Jupyter. Please note that when I do

```
pip list
```

it shows me all the libraries and it has gensim there.

Answer (score 2):

`pip list` will not show you conda modules
try `conda list` to ensure you have the gensim module installed

EDIT:

Also ensure your kernelspec and the python interpreter are pointing to the same enviroment

http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/kernelspec.html

Answer (score 2):

this question is old but since google dropped me here, for others, I had to install jupyter for that conda environment, because it was also installed globally which wasn't seeing my env packages.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're running Jupyter with a different Python interpreter. See what this prints in the notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Do the directories listed look similar or different from the ones you saw when starting Python in the terminal?

Comment: I received the same error. I can import gensim in python terminal, but can't import it  in iPython. What's the issue? Both my python and gensim are installed in my own anaconda environment.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, after installing gensim in a virtual environment with

```
conda install -c conda-forge gensim
```

You have to re-install jupyter with:

```
conda install jupyter
```

Otherwise jupyter will open the kernel and the `sys.path` of the base environment, and thus will not recognize gensim and `import gensim` will not work.

I have no idea why is that, maybe the gensim conda package is broken.

**EDIT:**

If jupyter is installed with the previous command, you have to force reinstallation as follows:

```
conda update jupyter --force-reinstall --no-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute in command prompt:

```
pip install gensim
```

will solve the problem "No module named gensim"

Comment: The question clearly states that the OP installed gemsim. Total off-topic answer

Comment: I just had the exact same problem today, and this is the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I found myself with the same issue today. And all I had to do, to get it working properly, was to click on "Update index", for installed packages in the Environment menu of Anaconda. A little print to illustrate:

[image]